# Is there a way to pass signal arguments through QStateMachine QState transitions?

Tags: python, pyqt, qstatemachine

For example, let's say I have some `QButtonBucket` class containing some number *N* `QPushButton`s within it, and I want pushing any of those buttons to cause a transition from some state to another. This is simple enough:

```
for button in button_bucket.get_buttons():
    state_1.addTransition(button.clicked, state_2)
```

However, let's say I want to do something with the source `QPushButton` that causes the transition, such as changing its color if the transition is from `state_1` to `state_2`, or maybe disabling it if the transition is from `state_3` back to `state_1`

I want to handle this within the tight bounds of the `QStateMachine` logic due to the asynchronous nature of `QStateMachine`s. I don't want to have to track what button was clicked, or any other stateful data for that matter, within `QButtonBucket`.

If there was a way to acquire arguments passed along with the signal identified in `addTransition`, and act on them after the new state is entered, that would be pretty much perfect. But I'm not seeing an easy solution to implement that.

Is there a known-good way of achieving what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QState.assignProperty (self, QObject object, str name, QVariant value)` function which instructs a state to set a property of an object when the state is entered. So something like this could be done:

```
state_1.assignProperty(button, "enabled", false)
```

Comment: That's something I looked at, however as I said we're talking multiple buttons, where you need to know which button to apply styling to, and storing the identity of the source button externally from the state machine defeats its stateliness.